# Display data from Angularjs2 file(.ts) in html page

Tags: javascript, html, angular, web, typescript

code in my .ts file is

```
  constructor(
      private config  :  ConfigService,
      private http: Http){ 
      this.getWS('ngoName')
      .do((data) => {
        console.log(data);
        this.saveObj(data);
      }).toPromise();
}

saveObj(data:any){
  this.profileObj = data;
  console.log(this.profileObj);    
}   

  getWS(ngoName:string):any{  
    return this.http.get(this.config.serverBaseURL + "ngos.php?ngoId=1")
        .map((res: Response) => res.json());            
  }
```

the object which i have to use in my html file is the profileObj, structure of profileObj is like this

```
{
  "statusCode"   : "200",
   "message"     : "success",
   "ngoDetails"  : [
{"ngoId":"1","ngoName":"Test 1","emailId":"ritesh@gmail.com"}]}
```

but when i am giving {{profileObj.statusCode}} i am getting error:

> zone.js:357 Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Error in ./Profile
>   class Profile - inline template:28:9 caused by: Cannot read property
>   'statusCode' of undefined

please help me to resolve this error.

Comment: Whats the output in console when you run `console.log(this.profileObj);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use "?" notation in your HTML , if profileObj exists only then it will search for statusCode

```
{{profileObj?.statusCode}}
```

Comment: amazing..this is legendary